# Compile with javac and convert double to float

Tags: java, compilation, javac

Is it possible to set an compile option to compile this directly:

```
float f = 1.0;
```

I do not like to add the 'f' or 'F' after the '1.0'. So, can I tell the compiler to convert the double directly into a float?

Thank you for every answer.

Comment: No, there are no compiler options to do what you want. Java is a fairly strict language with no variations allowed, unlike C/C++.

Comment: It is required by the JLS so... you better start to like it. Or stop using floats :)

Comment: Add an `F` (or `f`) after the `1.0`, (or add a cast like `(float) 1.0;`).

Comment: "I do not like to add the 'f' or 'F' after the '1.0'" - why not? No, you can't violate the rules of the Java language like this - I suggest you just get used to using the suffix.

Comment: Thank you all for you answers. I just wondered because I think it would be pretty easy to change the compiler to convert this automatically.

Comment: @Kanteran The problem is not the compiler, it's the humans. It is very easy to add this feature. It's hard to deal with the confusion to programmers, because now they have to worry about a new mode of operation.

Comment: @NayukiMinase but why should this bring trouble? This would take only effect if an variable is  about to init?

Comment: Because now you have to tell other people to compiler your Java code with special, non-standard compiler options.

Comment: @Kanteran no, those literals are used everywhere in expressions, like `2.0*(f-0.8)`. Even if you write a non-standard compiler that treats 1.0 as float then your code won't run in others' compilers and they don't know why

Comment: Oh, but as default setting? ;)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want/need to use `float` over `double` anyway? This tastes like micro-optimisation.

Comment: @Phylogenesis no, there is no particular reason. A friend asked me and I searched an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such option in the Java compiler. It would create a slightly different, incompatible dialect of the Java programming language - which has been avoided up until now.

Generally speaking, the Java compiler and JVM are pretty strict in how they treat the language. There are very, very few options that can affect the behavior of source code at compile time or the logic at run time.

For example, these are options that do not exist in Java (but may exist in other languages):

- Make compilation case-insensitive.
- Run the C preprocessor on Java source code (for macros, includes, etc.).
- Skip all array index checks at run time.
- Throw an exception on `int` overflow.

The options that do exist are rather mundane:

- Java compiler: Language version for the source code.
- Java compiler: Character set of source file.
- JVM memory limits.
- JVM garbage collection algorithm tuning.

---

As a side note, some compile-time behaviors are even mandated by the Java Language Specification. For example, certain types of [unreachable code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) are compile-time errors, and a compliant Java compiler must flag it as an error (not as a warning or ignore):

```
while (true) { ... }
foo();  // Compile-time error
```

Second example:

```
return;
bar();  // Compile-time error
```

(This contrasts with C/C++, where unreachable code detection is an optional diagnostic provided by compilers to help a programmer; it is not required behavior.)

Comment: jvm tuning is not compiler tuning.Its the tuning of runtime virtual machine

Comment: Why should the compiler prevent to compile unreachable code. I think the programmer should know what he wrote?

Comment: The detection of unreachable code has saved me from countless mistakes over the years; it's a useful feature. I work quickly, so I only glance at pieces of code for a few seconds and not read carefully. But the problem is, I'm not sure if unreachable code should be treated as a *mandatory error* like in Java or just a *convenience diagnostic* like in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

Can compiler options be customized? Yes, only for backward compatibility.

Is your case an example of backward compatibility? **No**.

Example: Until Java 1.4, `assert` was not a keyword and could be used as a variable. When compiling an `assert` keyword, you can use it to be used as a lower compiled class.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the compiler settings. You can typecast to float if you want if you don't wish to use f at the end. You can read more on [primitive data types][1] here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html